# Section 508 compliant Gridview

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, section508, wcag

Is it possible to have a Gridview Section 508 compliant covering both point g & h?

Link for section 508 http://www.access-board.gov/sec508/guide/1194.22.htm
Link for ASP.Net Section 508 Compliance http://www.patuee.com/web/ASPX_Accessibility.html#t7

Comment: Why not start with a ListView and save yourself a ton of trouble?

Comment: I am alloted a project which has to go Section 508 compliant :|

Comment: A link to the relevant 508 sections might encourage others to take a look :)

Comment: @IrishChieftain Updated with links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and googling I found the solution. I have written down below code and called it in RowDataBound event.

private void AddGridHeadersAttr(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e, GridView Grid)

```
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col <= e.Row.Cells.Count - 1; col++)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[col].Attributes.Add("id", "ColumnHeader_" + Grid.Columns[col].HeaderText);
        }
    }
    else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col <= e.Row.Cells.Count - 1; col++)
        {
            Object oCell = e.Row.Cells[col];
            if (oCell is DataControlFieldHeaderCell)
            {
                ((DataControlFieldHeaderCell)oCell).Attributes.Add("id", "RowHeader_" + Grid.Columns[col].HeaderText + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString());//Grid.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                ((DataControlFieldCell)oCell).Attributes.Add("headers", "ColumnHeader_" + Grid.Columns[col].HeaderText + " RowHeader_" + Grid.Columns[col].HeaderText + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString()); // Grid.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone in future.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with GridView is that the tables are auto-generated, so a conversion to ListView would pay off effort-wise; you could then display table markup any way you want in ListView templates.

In order to get the GridView to do this, you would have to create a new custom control GridView which inherits from the out-of-the-box one. Then you could customize the table rendering output of the new control. Many examples of custom GridViews out there :)

According to Microsoft, accessibility can be accomplished with the GridView:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228004.aspx#guideline_13__separating_structure_from_presentation

Comment: please check the above answer